# How to return to launch inside of the collect?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a method that looks like that:

```
private lateinit var cards: List<Card>

fun start() = viewModelScope.launch {
    if (!::cards.isInitialized) {
        getCards().collect { result ->
            result
                .doIfSuccess {
                    cards = it.data
                    Log.d(TAG, "Received cards")
                }
                .doIfError {
                    _errorState.setIfNotEqual(it.exception)
                    Log.e(TAG, "Cards were not received because of ${it.exception}")
                    return@collect // <--- that's the place
                }
        }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Message that needs to be shown only if cards were received")

    if (сards.isEmpty()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Сards list is empty")
        _errorState.setIfNotEqual(NoCardsException)
        return@launch
    }

    val сard = сards[0]
}
```

I need to completely return from the method, not only from the `.collect` block, I've tried to use `return@launch` or some other custom labels, but it doesn't work even though Kotlin compiler suggests me to set it like that:

[image]

Comment: Are `.doIfSuccess` and `.doIfError` inline functions?

Comment: yes, they both are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `transformWhile` to create a new Flow that does an operation on each item you receive until you return false. Then collect that Flow. I didn't test this because I'm not really sure of how you've structured `.doIfSuccess` and `.doIfError`.

```
fun start() = viewModelScope.launch {
    if (!::cards.isInitialized) {
        getCards().transformWhile { result ->
            result
                .doIfSuccess {
                    cards = it.data
                    Log.d(TAG, "Received cards")
                }
                .doIfError {
                    _errorState.setIfNotEqual(it.exception)
                    Log.e(TAG, "Cards were not received because of ${it.exception}")
                    return@transformWhile false
                }
            return@transformWhile true
        }.collect()
    }

    //...
}
```

EDIT:
If you only want the first value from the Flow, you could do this:

```
fun start() = viewModelScope.launch {
    if (!::cards.isInitialized) {
        getCards().first()
            .doIfSuccess {
                cards = it.data
                Log.d(TAG, "Received cards")
            }
            .doIfError {
                _errorState.setIfNotEqual(it.exception)
                Log.e(TAG, "Cards were not received because of ${it.exception}")
                return@launch
            }
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: sorry if I'm wrong, but isn't this code behaves the same way as return@collect? the problem is that I need to return from the whole method completely if I get into `doIfError` block

Comment: `return@collect` returns from that cycle of the lambda being called, but it is set up to run the lambda over and over. Returning from a lambda that is called repeatedly is analogous to calling `continue` in a for loop rather than `break`. By using `transformWhile`, you can break the loop by returning `false`.

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood your problem. Does this Flow only have one item emitted? I thought you were having trouble breaking out of collection. If it only emits a single value, why isn’t it just a suspend function rather than a Flow?

Comment: this flow emits lists of cards from different datasources(persistence and network); there is a problem with breaking out of the entire `start()` method ;( it should look like that: cards received -> code runs forward, but if cards were not received -> break `start()` method

Comment: So you want to break out on the first value from the Flow, whether it came from persistence or network? Is this a Flow that completes on its own, or continues forever until cancelled?

Comment: In this particular case it emits values only from network datasource, so I need to break out only if I catch an error(disconnected from server in example); I'm not cancelling it

Comment: Did you see my edit? Still not sure what you're doing. If you collect from a Flow that's never cancelled, you'll keep getting values as long as it keeps emitting if you don't break out in some way. You could use `first()` to just grab the first value emitted and continue from there.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your edit, but I think it is what I need. Thank you!